# Proving a set is a Dedekind cut

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

For a set $A$ to be a Dedekind cut in $\mathbb Q$, it must not be the empty set, must not be equal to $\mathbb Q$, must have no maximal element, and if $x \in A$, then for all $y < x$, $y \in \mathbb Q$ implies $y \in A$.

For the set $C_r := \{ q \in \mathbb Q : q < r \}$ for any $r \in \mathbb Q$, when proving it has no maximal element, do I just do $r$ is not an element in $C_r$, but $r-1/n \in C_r$, $n \in \mathbb N$ and by the archimedean principle we can make $1/n$ arbitrarily small?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on to the right track, and your argument will work, though perhaps you need to be a bit clearer on why exactly this makes $C_r$ not have a maximal element.

I personally think that this should be proven more directly. Take an arbitrary $x\in C_r$ and construct a $y\in C_r$ that is larger (using $x$ and $r$ in the construction might be a good idea). This proves that no number can be the largest.

Comment: Thanks very much, I think I see what your saying having y be the mean of x and r?

Comment: @Spudnick That would be the easiest one, yes, although if you want to make it complicated for no real reason, there are plenty of other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes. Specifically, for any candidate $m=\max C_r$, there is $n$ such that $0<\frac1n<r-m$.